Identifying a psychological drama from the early 2000s?
I'm trying to find a color (probably American) English movie which I watched about 10 years ago. I have a very vague memory of it, but it was probably a fairly recent movie (late 90s/early 2000s).
The plot revolves around a man who lives in a progressively horrific dream (psychologically horrific). In the end he has to jump off a building in order to escape/wake up. 
I think it turned out that he had been crygenically frozen. I did not understand the movie very well (I was about 12 years old at the time), but I recall that I found it pretty frighting. It gave me about the same feeling as "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind".

I think You're looking for Vanilla Sky, starring Tom Cruise, Penelope Cruz and Cameron Diaz.
The movie is categorized on wikipedia as:

Vanilla Sky is a 2001 American science fiction psychological thriller film [...].

Plot from wikipedia:

David finds himself in the empty lobby of the offices, and the man whom he saw earlier at the bar appears, claiming to be David's tech support from Life Extension, which is now known as the Oasis Project[...]. The man explains that David has been in cryonic sleep for 150 years. [...] As they arrive at the top of the building, the man offers David a choice: either to be reinserted into the corrected lucid dream, or return to the real world by taking a literal leap of faith off the roof that will wake him from his sleep. David decides to wake up [...]. Conquering his final fear, David jumps off the building, his life flashing before his eyes, and whites out immediately before hitting the ground. A female voice commands him to "open your eyes" (a recurring theme in the movie), and the film ends with David opening his eyes.

Trailer:



The ending scene:




@Uncountable It is a remake of the movie "Abre los ojos" (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0125659/), so you might be interested in the original as well.

Yes and that is also the last thing we can hear in the movie "open your eyes" said by Penelope Cruz who is also starring in "Abre los ojos" ("open your eyes" in english).
